# Change prop value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, tsx

I am working on an old app which used to have the following `index.tsx`

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { MyApp, MyAppProps } from './components';

function init(element: HTMLElement, options: MyAppProps) {
  ReactDOM.render(<MyApp {...options} />, element);
}
```

The object `MyAppProps` is an interface with few defaults. Because I want to be able to change one of these defaults based on the URLParams, I thought to introduce a simple

```js
const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);  
const myKey = queryParams.get('myKey')
```

and then pass the `myKey` with a line like this

`let MyAppProps.key = myKey`

but it does not work. I cannot figure out how to correctly construct this piece of code. It seems I should create an object of the same type of the interface so that I can manipulate, but all my tests are failing.

Comment: `<MyApp {...options} key={myKey}/>` should work.

Comment: `key` is a special property used in lists, so it probably wouldn't work. Please add the definition of `MyAppProps`, and is `key` the actual name?

Comment: @OriDrori `key` is an example here. The real definition in the interface is `rootType?: string`

Comment: @Oblosys it works. Unfortunately, I've realized  that the definition of `MyAppProps` includes a nested interface and the property I need to touch is into the nested interface. 
`key.subkey={MyKey}` does not work in this case. Calling only `subKey={MyKey}` does not work either.

Comment: In that case it would be something like `<MyApp {...options} key={{...options.key, subKey: myKey}}/>` (with meta-syntactic `key` being the name of the prop to override). If you add the actual prop types to the question, it will be easier to formulate an answer.

Comment: @Oblosys it works perfectly. Although, it does not do what I wanted :) I need to investigate. The `function init` initialize and start the app, the options is the exported interface which contains all the props, but somehow if I change a default it does not work as expected.
It might be also the case for me to use the `react-router` within the App.